# What's the minimum clock cycles number to read and write with AXI4Lite

Tags: arm, xilinx, hdl, bus, amba

I'm wondering what is the minimum number of clock cycle to do a simple access on an AXI4Lite bus.

I think it's 4, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In theory, you can have single cycle (combinatorial) transaction, but that's not practical in most cases, so two cycles - one for address and one for data is the practical minimum. This ignores the B-channel in write, which is quite typical.

If you want to know what's the minimum in your IP, just tie READY signals to '1' and see what happens.